# Plot Fourier in Frequency domain of Voice in Python

Tags: python, plot, signal-processing, fft, frequency

Iam facing a very strange problem with my plots. My  code records my voice from the microphone and then makes some plots. A plot of voice in time domain, a plot in frequency domain and a spectrogramm. The problem is that my plot in frequency domain does not seems to be true. For example have a look at my plots.
[image]
[image]
[image]

So in this record iam saying 'one, two, three, four' or something like that. The time  domain plot does make sense. The spectrogram also in my eyes does make sense because the loudest Fourier magnitudes are at normal human voice frequencies ~100 Hz.

##### The problem is

My short time fourier transform  in frequency domain plot, seems to plot very high frequencies with very high magnitude, and the human voice frequencies 1-1000 have zero value.

So what maybe is going wrong?
Below i give my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.fft
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy import signal, fft

Fs = 8000  # Sampling frequency
duration = 5  # Recording duration in seconds
voice = sd.rec(frames=duration * Fs, samplerate=Fs, channels=1, dtype='int16')  # Capture the voice
# frames indicate  indirectly the duration of record, dtype is 16 bits per sample.
sd.wait()  # close after recording finish
time = np.linspace(0, len(voice - 1) / Fs, len(voice - 1))  # split x axis in voice-1 points
# points have 1/Fs distance each other
plt.plot(voice / len(voice))
plt.ylabel('Voice amplitude')
plt.xlabel('No of sample')
plt.title("Voice Signal with respect to sample number")
plt.show()
plt.plot(time, voice / len(voice))  # plot in seconds
plt.title("Voice Signal")
plt.xlabel("Time [seconds]")
plt.ylabel("Voice amplitude")
plt.show()
plt.plot((10**3)*time, voice / len(voice))  # plot in milliseconds
plt.title("Voice Signal")
plt.xlabel("Time [milliseconds]")
plt.ylabel("Voice amplitude")
plt.show()
N = len(voice)
# Fourier transform
F = scipy.fft.fft(voice) / N
#f = np.linspace(0, Fs - Fs / N, N)
f = fft.fftfreq(n=N, d=1 / Fs)[:N // 2]
#f = np.linspace(0, 4000, N//2)
plt.plot(f, abs(F[0:N // 2]))
plt.title("FFT of the signal")
plt.xlabel('Frequency')
plt.ylabel('Power of Frequency')
plt.show()
Voice = voice.flatten()  # formatting Voice 2-D array to numpy 1-D array
print(Voice)
freq, t, stft = signal.spectrogram(Voice, Fs, mode='complex')
#Sxx, freq, t = plt.specgram(Voice, Fs=Fs, mode='magnitude')
print(stft)
print(freq)
print(t)
plt.pcolormesh(t, freq, abs(stft), shading='gouraud')
plt.title('Spectrogramm using STFT amplitude')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [seconds]')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try plotting your stft data in decibels ```stft_db = 20*np.log10(abs(stft))``` and plotting that using your pcolormesh command.  Then higher harmonics will be easier to see.  Your spectrogram plot does indeed seem reasonable for voice data considering the linear scale.

Comment: ... and add a colorbar for a nice touch: ```plt.colorbar()```

Comment: Your advice is about spectrogram? There is not a problem. The problem is about stft-frequency plot (second plot). You can see in the second plot to high values for for too high frequencies, but my voice frequencies have zero value

Comment: Yes, agreed the second plot looks wonky

Comment: Can you see something suspicious in my code? In Matlab for example it is very easy to make a linspace for the frequency axis and then just add as second argument abs(Stft) inside plot(). On the other hand i write an extremly same working code, but the results differ too much

Comment: Check out the answer from @SleuthEye , i think that's a good lead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the 2D array `voice` (most likely Nx1, for mono recording), `scipy.fft.fft` ends up computing a batch of N 1D FFTs of length 1. Since the FFT of a sequence of 1 value is an identity, what you see in your 2nd plot is the absolute value of the first half of your time domain signal.

Try computing the FFT on a 1D array (a single channel), with e.g. :

```
F = scipy.fft.fft(voice[:,0]) / N
```

Comment: And later he does `Voice = voice.flatten()` for stft which is also wrong

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you VERY MUCH. Iam in general new in python an extremely new in digital signal processing with python. I knew the basic principles of signal and systems, but really this issue has to do with some ''stranges of python''. Also i noted tha you also observed that my second plot, was the same with the first, cutting of the negative values.

Comment: @dankal i flattened the array because i had an error with dimensions inside signal.spectogram and pcoloromesh, so i had to do that, but know i flatten the array before the fft.fft(voice) and all functions works with the initial flatten

Comment: @Panos Ok, Just remember if you will analyse stereo recording you will have 2 channels - Nx2 samples - and flattening will be incorrect.

Comment: Yes, i think i understand the point. If  i had stereo i will had  a big array with many 2-element arrays. In this case, actually, i cannot imagine how my spectogramm and pcolormesh would work and if error occured, but ok when the time comes i will try to manage it